# VB.NET Fake ProgressBar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

i want to make fake progress bar 
when i click on the button:

```
for i = 0 to Maximum 
progressbar1.value = progressbar1.value + 1
next
```

but the progressbar.value = 100 Too fast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use timer,
button:

```
timer1.enable = true
```

timer:

```
   If ProgressBar1.value = ProgressBar1.maximum Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ProgressBar1.value = ProgressBar1.value + 1
```

Comment: it works now :) , I'm not thought about this option, thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like...

```
for i = 0 to Maximum 
    progressbar1.value = progressbar1.value + 1
    Pause(5)
next

Public Sub Pause(ByRef seconds As Double)
    Dim fIni as DateTime = Now.AddSeconds(seconds)

    While Now < fIni
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: DoEvents should be avoided have a look at [this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html)

Comment: If you want to pause, why not just use Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Sorry, when I saw the question I just grabbed some old code I had written for a web scraper, and My.Application.DoEvents() worked well for refreshing the web control and loading the page. I don't believe I tried using Thread.Sleep, and have now switched over to mainly PHP. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You generally show progress when something is taking a long time so you can show the progress to the user.

```
    For i = 0 To ProgressBar1.Maximum - 1
        'some long running process happens here 
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    Next
```

If you want to simulate a logn running process for testing etc you can use a Sleep

```
    For i = 0 To ProgressBar1.Maximum - 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) 'wait for 50ms
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    Next
```

*However*

The preferred way of doing this is to execute your long running process in a background worker and update the progress bar using a delegate when it has finished. But that is another question.